# Horizontally aligned radio buttons with another text box

Tags: jquery, html

What is the correct HTML for two radio inputs and a text box under the same label? Below is the fiddle for what I have so far. I want the user the select either *YES*, *NO* or *Other*. If *Other* is selected, I'd like to display the hidden text box (which must be required). What is the best way of doing that? If someone could fix the jQuery and HTML, I would greatly appreciate it. Also, I have multiple inputs like this on my form, so I want the code to be as generic as possible. Thanks in advance.

```js
$("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
  if($(this).val()=="other")
    $(this).closest("div").find("input[name=hidden-other]").css('display', 'inline-block');
  else
    $(this).closest("div").find("input[name=hidden-other]").css('display', 'none'); 
});
```

```css
input.hidden-other{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="during-or-after">During or After Office Hours  *</label>
  <input type="radio" name="during-or-after" value="during" checked>During
  <input class="radio-with-left-margin" type="radio" 
         name="during-or-after" value="after">After
  <input class="radio-with-left-margin" type="radio" 
         name="during-or-after" value="other" >Other
  <input type="text" name="hidden-other" 
         class="hidden-other" id="hidden-other" required>
</div>
```

Comment: your Fiddle works--you just had't selected JQuery as a JS library https://jsfiddle.net/alsosun/czqqt0fa/4/

Comment: im a little concerned about my for and name attributes not matching. Is my way okay for implementing all three inputs inside the same label. I heard that you can only have one input for a particular "for" attribute.

Comment: Yes, you will have issues with your code if you add more groups of inputs and labels because you are referencing the the parent div by id. Easy way to fix it is to use wrap a div around each set with a class. see this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/alsosun/czqqt0fa/10/ I changed `id="parent' ` to `class="parent"` then changed the selector to `$(this).closest(".parent")`

Comment: The other input box is being displayed below the radio. How can I show it on the same line?

Comment: Oh never mind. Just removed the <br> haha. Everything else looks good? There shouldn't be any issues on the server side due to 'for' and 'name' attributes? Sorry, first time implementing forms.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/czqqt0fa/7/) ?

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
  <div style="float: left;">
    <label for="during-or-after">During or After Office Hours *</label>
    <input type="radio" name="during-or-after" value="during" checked>During
    <input class="radio-with-left-margin" type="radio" name="during-or-after" value="after">After
  </div>
  <div style="float: left;">
    <input class="radio-with-left-margin" type="radio" name="during-or-after" value="other">Other
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="hidden-other" class="hidden-other" id="hidden-other" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With CSS only:

```css
input[type="radio"] + input[type="text"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + input[type="text"] {
  display: inline;
  /* <-----you need to use inline to display it after text "Other" */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="during-or-after">During or After Office Hours *</label>
  <input type="radio" name="during-or-after" value="during" checked>During
  <input class="radio-with-left-margin" type="radio" name="during-or-after" value="after">After
  <input class="radio-with-left-margin" type="radio" name="during-or-after" value="other">Other
  <input type="text" name="hidden-other" class="hidden-other" id="hidden-other" required>
</div>
```